# [javascript webdriverIO} select one random out of Xpath with multiple nodes

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, webdriver-io

Im trying to get one random node out of a Xpath with multiple nodes. the number of nodes is variable and changes every week. I need 1 of the following 2 solutions to work:

1. get a number back of the number of nodes corresponding to this Xpath. in that way i can use it to randomize it
2. an other option that will give the same result: give me 1 of e.g 25 Xpaths at random.

i tried to tackle this problem in different ways. but none have worked so far.
I came across this solution:

```
productCounter(){
        let c = document.evaluate('count(//*[@itemtype]/*[@data-order-bacu])', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
        console.log(c.numberValue);
}
```

It should give me the number of nodes in a Xpath, which i then could use to randomize the correct number of nodes.  but since i use webdriverIO it will give the error:

> document is not defined

So i tried something different and used the "browser.elements" function of webdriverIO. but om not sure if that helps.

`productCounter(){
        let a = browser.selectByIndex("//*[@itemtype]/*[@data-order-bacu]");
        console.log (a);
    }`

Console.log will give me back something like, see below. Is this usable in some way to get the number of nodes aswell.

```
{ sessionId: 'a45061ba0d9dfcf0b241877bb2951cc8',
  value:
   [ { ELEMENT: '0.5928327282420562-1',
       'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '0.5928327282420562-1',
       selector: '//*[@itemtype]/*[@data-order-bacu]',
       value: [Object],
       index: 0 },
     { ELEMENT: '0.5928327282420562-2',
       'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '0.5928327282420562-2',
       selector: '//*[@itemtype]/*[@data-order-bacu]',
       value: [Object],
       index: 1 },
     { ELEMENT: '0.5928327282420562-3',
       'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '0.5928327282420562-3',
       selector: '//*[@itemtype]/*[@data-order-bacu]',
       value: [Object],
       index: 2 },
     { ELEMENT: '0.5928327282420562-4',
       'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '0.5928327282420562-4',
       selector: '//*[@itemtype]/*[@data-order-bacu]',
       value: [Object],
       index: 3 },
     { ELEMENT: '0.5928327282420562-5',
       'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '0.5928327282420562-5',
       selector: '//*[@itemtype]/*[@data-order-bacu]',
       value: [Object],
       index: 4 },
     { ELEMENT: '0.5928327282420562-6',
       'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '0.5928327282420562-6',
       selector: '//*[@itemtype]/*[@data-order-bacu]',
       value: [Object],
       index: 5 },
     { ELEMENT: '0.5928327282420562-7',
       'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '0.5928327282420562-7',
       selector: '//*[@itemtype]/*[@data-order-bacu]',
       value: [Object],
       index: 6 },
     { ELEMENT: '0.5928327282420562-8',
       'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '0.5928327282420562-8',
       selector: '//*[@itemtype]/*[@data-order-bacu]',
       value: [Object],
       index: 7 },
     { ELEMENT: '0.5928327282420562-9',
       'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '0.5928327282420562-9',
       selector: '//*[@itemtype]/*[@data-order-bacu]',
       value: [Object],
       index: 8 } ],
  selector: '//*[@itemtype]/*[@data-order-bacu]',
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oke, i found the awnser to this question:

```
randomCake(Option){
        let a = browser.elements("//*[@itemtype]/*[@data-order-bacu]");
        let random = Math.floor(Math.random()*a.value.length);
        browser.elementIdElement(a.value[random].ELEMENT.toString(), '.add-to-cart__submit').click();
        }
```

*'add-to-cart__submit'* was in this case an extra i needed to add to the path since every node/element has 4 buttons